# wpf text box error provider not working

Tags: c#, wpf, csla

I have a very simple wpf form that contains a text box that binds to a CSLA business object(Version 4.5.7). I'm assigning the the property *AText* a *String.Empty*.

The Error provider should gets activated when the window is initially loaded since it is a required field. However it is activated when I start typing the first character which is fine since I have the minimum character attribute field set to 5 characters. When I erase all characters from the box the error provider stays on which also fine.

Why the error provider is not getting activated when the window is loaded ?

Thank you

## wpf

```
  <Grid>
     <TextBox Height="50" Width="300" Text="{Binding AText, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
    </Grid>
```

## C#

```
namespace TestNameSpace
    {
    [Serializable()]
    public class CSLAClass : BusinessBase<CSLAClass>
        {
          public CSLAClass()
            {
            AText = String.Empty;
            }
        public static PropertyInfo<string> ATextProperty = RegisterProperty<string>(p => p.AText);
        [Required, MinLength(5,ErrorMessage ="The Minimum is 5"), MaxLength(10)]
        public string AText
            {
            get { return GetProperty(ATextProperty); }
            set { SetProperty(ATextProperty, value); }
            }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling BusinessRules.CheckRules prior to returning from your DataPortal_Create / DataPortal_Fetch?  The rules don't run automatically from those, so the object will start out as valid.